# How to check when a user is self_deaf in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have been trying to move a player that is deafened but I always seem to run into errors that won't detect when they are deafened and moving them:

```py
async def isdeaf(ctx):
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(760190547108298852)
    members = voice_channel.members
    for member in members:
        if members.voice_state(760190547108298852, self_deaf=True):
                print(1)
                channel = client.get_channel(789256316437659658)
                await member.move_to(member, channel)
        else:
            print(2)
                
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    client.loop.create_task(isdeaf(ctx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line

```py
if members.voice_state(760190547108298852, self_deaf=True):
```

It just doesn't make sense, `members` is a list, it doesn't have the attribute `voice_state`

Your code fixed:

```py
async def isdeaf(ctx):
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(760190547108298852)
    channel_to_move = client.get_channel(789256316437659658)
    members = voice_channel.members

    for member in members:
        if member.voice.self_deaf:
            # Member is defeaned, move it here
            await member.move_to(channel_to_move)
```